# return number of results from scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape INDEED:COM. I need python to return me the number of results corresponding to the research of job "data scientist" and city "milan". I think it can be done by "extracting the number of result displayed in the page" or by counting the number of results of the search (which is what I tried to do in passage 1) and 2)). 
First time i use python in my life, and I need this to get done for a project when this easy search is the starting point of a buisiness project. 
Can you help me programming it to return number of results???
Thanks indeed for the help you all!!

```
##import something 
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

##tell python what I am looking for 
URL="""https://it.indeed.com/offerte-lavoro?q=data&l=lombardia&start=20"""
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"html.parser")
#print(soup.prettify())

##extract the job tile (didnt work)
def extract_job_title_from_result(soup): 
 jobs = []
 for div in soup.find_all(name="div",attrs={"class":"row"}):
     for a in div.find_all(name="a",attrs={"data-tn-element":"jobTitle"}):
       jobs.append(a["title"])
 return(jobs)
output = extract_job_title_from_result(soup)
print (output)

### 1) count the results
URL_for_count = "https://it.indeed.com/offerte-lavoro?q=data&l=lombardia&start=20".format(query, location)
soup_for_count = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(URL_for_count).read(), 'html.parser')
results_number = soup_for_count.find("div", attrs = {"id": "searchCount"}).text
number_of_results = int(results_number.split(sep = ' ')[-1].replace(',', ''))


### 2) reiterate the search through the different pages of Indeed, to get ALL of the results 
##nober of results shown per page = 10
i = int(number_of_results/100)
    for page_number in range(i + 1):
        URL_for_results = "https://it.indeed.com/Milano,-Lombardia-offerte-lavoro-data-scientist".format(query, location, str(100 * page_number))
        soup_for_results = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(URL_for_results).read(), 'html.parser')
        results = soup_for_results.find_all('div', attrs={'data-tn-component': 'organicJob'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `find_all` method from BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib
data = str(urllib.urlopen('https://it.indeed.com/offerte-lavoro?q=data&l=lombardia&start=20').read())
listing = soup(data, 'lxml')
jobs = [i.text[1:-1] for i in listing.find_all('h2')]
print(jobs)
print("number of jobs is: {}".format(len(jobs)))
```

Output:

```
[u'Data Scientist', u'Data Scientist', u'Junior Data Analyst', u'Oracle Data Integrator Junior', u'Junior Data Warehouse', u'Data Scientist/Biostatistician', u'URGENTE - RICERCA IMPIEGATO UFFICIO ORDINI / DATA ENTRY', u'Data Scientist with Machine Learning', u'DATA SCIENTIST- MACHINE LEARNING EXPERT', u'7224 Internal Audit - Quantitative Analyst']

number of jobs is: 10
```

Edit: to get the data for the first six pages:

```
final_data = [[b.text[1:-1] for b in soup(str(urllib.urlopen("https://it.indeed.com/offerte-lavoro?q=data&l=lombardia&start={}".format(10*i)).read()), "lxml").find_all('h2')] for i in range(6)]
lengths = list(map(len, final_data))
print(sum(lengths))
```

Output:

```
[[u'Data Scientist \u2013 Social Media Intelligence', u'DATA ANALYST', u'Data Analyst', u'Data Analyst', u'Data Analyst', u'Data Analyst', u'Data Analyst', u'Data Entry Specialist', u'Impiegato Data Entry', u'Data Scientist'], [u'Junior Data Scientist', u'DATA ANALYST JR \u2013 Milano', u'STAGE JUNIOR DATA ANALYST / DATA SCIENTIST BIG DATA', u'Machine Learning Scientist', u'Data Analyst', u'Data Analyst (Econometric modeling) Sede di Milano', u'Neolaureati in statistica, matematica, ingegneria-Data Scien...', u'Data Scientist', u'Data Scientist', u'Data Scientist'], [u'Data Scientist', u'Data Scientist', u'Junior Data Analyst', u'Oracle Data Integrator Junior', u'Junior Data Warehouse', u'Data Scientist/Biostatistician', u'URGENTE - RICERCA IMPIEGATO UFFICIO ORDINI / DATA ENTRY', u'Data Scientist with Machine Learning', u'DATA SCIENTIST- MACHINE LEARNING EXPERT', u'7224 Internal Audit - Quantitative Analyst'], [u'Collaboratori Data Entry', u'Data Scientist', u'DATA ENTRY', u'Consumer Data Scientist', u'DATA ANALYST', u'JUNIOR - RISK ADVISORY - TECHNOLOGY & DATA RISK - PRODUCTS &...', u'Data Manager Ematologia', u'Data Scientist', u'Esperto Tecnologie Big Data \u2013 Text Analysis \u2013 Data Mining', u'Data Entry'], [u'People Data Analyst', u'Data Integration Analyst \u2013 TIBCO', u'ORACLE BI - Big Data Analytics', u'Data Strategist', u'Data Governance Specialist', u'Big Data Specialist', u'Oracle Data Integrator Specialist', u'Innovation Analyst', u'Data Scientist', u'Big Data Engineer'], [u'JUNIOR BIG DATA ENGINEER', u'Junior Payment Analyst', u'Esperti BIG DATa e DWH', u'Data Warehouse Manager', u'Data Analyst', u'Big Data Engineer', u'data entry part time', u'Big Data & Datawarehouse Architect Location: Milano', u'Biomedical Signal/Image Processing Data Analyst', u'IT Big Data Engineer']]
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
60
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the precious help. 
However, 10 is the number of jobs of the first page displayed by the website INDEED.com. I need to obtain the total number (as if the count-function could be reiterated through the several pages).
In fact, checking on the website, I can see that the real overlall resul is 60! (ten per each page). I need python to return automatically 60, and not 10.

Comment: You have been of great help! you are so helpful I'll try to stretch it one last time: Is there a way to tell him to do it for all the pages he finds instead of having to input "6"? (the idea is to create something that will be run many many times changing only the job-title)